# How to apply a condition to pandas iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I select columns `2 - end` from a pandas DataFrame with `iloc` as

```
d=c.iloc[:,2:]
```

now how can I apply a condition to this selection? For example, if `column1==1`.

Comment: Do you  think `d[d.column1==1]` ?

Comment: Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas) ? It seems dupe.

Comment: @jezrael you mean `c.loc[c[1] == 1]`? It gives `KeyError: 1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) if need filter first column select by position, `:` means here select all rows:

```
c[c.iloc[:, 0] == 1]
```

**Sample**:

```
c = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (c)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

df = c[c.iloc[:, 3] == 1]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
```

Comment: Why is this accepted as the answer, since it doesn't do what the question asks? In the question we want to keep only columns 2:.

Answer (score 6):

This is referred to as mixed indexing in that you want to index by boolean results in rows and position in columns.  I'd use `loc` in order to take advantage of boolean indexing for the rows.  But that implies that you need column names values for the column slice.

```
d.loc[d.column1 == 1, d.columns[2:]]
```

If your column names are not unique then you can resort to the dreaded chained index.

```
d.loc[d.column1 == 1].iloc[:, 2:]
```

What might also be intuitive is to use `query` afterwards:

```
d.iloc[:, 2:].query('column1 == 1')
```

Comment: Thanks, a great collection of various approaches! I learned a lot.