# How do I delete a row in my df based on a specific cell value "['0'] not found in axis"

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df and I am trying to see what the value is of the first row in the first column and if it is equal to a predetermined character in this case "0". I also tried:

```
if df[col_titles[0]].values[0] == x:
            print(True)
            df  = df.drop(x)
```

Which didn't work and had the exact same error (posted below).

```
  First Column Name Second Column Name Third Column Name Fourth Column Name
0                 0                  3                 6                  4
1                 2                  5                 5                  7

df = pd.DataFrame({'First Column Name':  ["0", 2],
        'Second Column Name': ["3", 5],
        'Third Column Name': ["6", 5],
        'Fourth Column Name': ["4", 7],
        })
col_titles = df.columns.values.tolist()
x = df[col_titles[0]].values[0]
print(x)

if df[col_titles[0]].values[0] == "0":
        print(True)
        df  = df.drop(df[col_titles[0]].values[0])
```

Returns

```
0
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    df  = df.drop(x)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3990, in drop
    return super().drop(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3936, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3970, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5017, in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['0'] not found in axis"
```

Desired output

```
  First Column Name Second Column Name Third Column Name Fourth Column Name
1                 2                  5                 5                  7
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a condition to pandas iloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292460/how-to-apply-a-condition-to-pandas-iloc)

Answer (score 1):

We do not for loop here

```
dfsub = df[df.iloc[:,0]!='0']
Out[13]: 
  First Column Name Second Column Name Third Column Name Fourth Column Name
1                 2                  5                 5                  7
```

Comment: @JPWilson yw :-) happy coding ~

Comment: Can I just ask what does the comma in front of the 0 do/mean?

Comment: @JPWilson I have that comma is mean we take the first column , `df.iloc[index , columns]` when we only care about the columns , we should pass the : to index ~

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the result you need:

```
df.loc[df['First Column Name'] != '0']
```

[image]